# Overriding == operator for class comparison C++

Tags: c++, boolean, overriding

I have a class S that contains several public member variables:

```
class S{
public:
    int l1;
    int r1;
    int b;
    int l2;
    int r2;
    // constructor and methods....
}
```

I'd like to compare classes, so I overrode the `==` operator like so:

```
bool operator==(const S &s1, const S &s2){
  if(s1.l1 != s2.l1)
    return false;
  if(s1.l2 != s2.l2)
    return false;
  if(s1.r1 != s2.r1)
    return false;
  if(s1.r2 != s2.r2)
    return false;
  if(s1.b != s2.b)
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

However, this simply isn't working at all- when I test it by creating two pointers to `S` objects and printing `S1 == S2` the result is 0, and I know the member variables are equal because I'm printing them too.

Am I doing something wrong with the way I'm overriding the operator?

Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm comparing pointers to `S` objects rather than `S` objects themselves?

Comment: Please update your post with the usage code that generates incorrect behavior (don't put code in comments).  Could it be that you are comparing pointers and not dereferencing before comparing (like using *p == *q)?

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statements are causing the issue?

Comment: Think of pointers as addresses of the objects; each object having a different address in memory.  Comparing pointers is equivalent to comparing the locations or addresses of the objects.  Comparing pointers does not compare the content of the objects they point to.

Comment: The example in this [article about `std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) has a very nice way of implementing comparison and equality in classes like yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, this simply isn't working at all- when I test it by creating two pointers to S objects and printing `S1 == S2` the result is 0

This is because operator `==` applies to objects, not pointers. Pointers are always compared using built-in comparison, hence you get a `false` back, unless the pointers actually point to the same exact object.

If you wish to compare the objects pointed to by your pointers, you need to do it like this:

```
if (*s1 == *s2)
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

When you compare 2 pointers you check if they point to the same address. If you want to use your operator - dereference them:

```
S *p1 = ...;
S *p2 = ...;

if( *p1 == *p2 ) // would compare objects rather than pointers
```

note: always be sure that pointers are not equal to `nullptr` before you dereference them.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're comparing the pointers. Pointers are just memory addresses, so the memory addresses MUST be different if they are allocated separately. Compare *S1 == *S2 to check if the objects they point to are the same.

Also, with an object like this (no pointers or anything), the default operator== should work perfectly fine. The compiler will create an operator== for you if you don't define one and in this case it would just compare ints, which it knows how to do.